# C# and tessaract error: "Only one image can be processed at once. Please make sure you dispose of the page once your finished with it."

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, tesseract

I am scaning pages with scanner via saraff.twain and then cheking if there is any text on page with tessaract. My code:

```
    private bool IsBlank(Bitmap image)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(tEngine.Process(image, PageSegMode.Auto).GetText()); 
    }

    public void DrawToPDF(int index)
    {
        try
        {
            // if get image, put in pdf via stream
            using (var image = twain.GetImage(index))
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                LOGGER.Debug("checking if blank...");
                using (Bitmap bitMapImage =  new Bitmap(image))
                {
                    if (!IsBlank(bitMapImage))
                    {
                        LOGGER.Debug("page is not blank, adding...");
                        PdfPage page = pdf.AddPage();
                        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
                        image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        // draw page
                        using (var xImage = XImage.FromStream(stream))
                        {
                            gfx.DrawImage(xImage, 0, 0, page.Width, page.Height);
                        }
                        LOGGER.Debug("page added.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LOGGER.Debug("page is blank, skip.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LOGGER.Warn(ex, $"error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

It works fine untill i call DrawToPDF second time and get "Only one image can be processed at once. Please make sure you dispose of the page once your finished with it.". To get what is wrong I used visual studio debugger and made snapshot before every DrawToPDF() call.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqh45.png)

The only new object added to memory before every new DrawToPDF() call was bitmap...

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Ku1.png)

I am confused... How am i supposed to make it right?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve]. The code, as is, does not compile (some of the variables aren't defined).

Comment: Well, I can try to create one, but it will require some scanner(or scanner simulator) with TWAIN support... Are you fine with it?

Answer (score 1):

> tEngine.Process(image, PageSegMode.Auto)

This call creates a Page object that is IDisposable. Tesseract requires destroying the Page object before calling the Process method again.

You can look at the conditions for the throw of an Exception in the [Tesseract
source code](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/blob/master/src/Tesseract/TesseractEngine.cs)

In your case, you just need to add using:

```
private bool IsBlank(Bitmap image)
{
     using(Page page = tEngine.Process(image, PageSegMode.Auto)) {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(page.GetText());
     }         
}
```